# FIlter state and update React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state

> I wanted to filter and update the state

```
    const [files, setFiles] = useState<[]>([]);

    ..... 
    setFiles(acceptedFiles);
    .....
  
    const handleRemoveSelected = (imageName: string) => {
    const update = files.filter((f: any) => f.name !== imageName);
    
    setFiles(update)(Error is here)
  
[![Error on setFile(update)][1]][1]};
```

**Error**
*Argument of type 'never[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<[]>'.
Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type '(prevState: []) => []'.
Type 'never[]' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: []): []'.ts(2345*

[image: error on setFile(update)]

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to specify the type in your `useState`, TS will infer that your `useState` is an array type only doing `useState([])`

Cahnge this:

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState<[]>([]);
```

To this:

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
```

Comment: thanks , i manage to solve it by defining types like this,

  const [fileSrc, setFileSrc] = useState<Picture[] | []>([]);